# I'm trying to solve "small triangles, large triangles" code on hackerrank, but i'm not getting expected output

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

> Problem details:- You are given n triangles, specifically, their sides a, b, and c . Print them in the same style but sorted by their areas from the smallest one to the largest one. It is guaranteed that all the areas are different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct temp_tri
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n)
{
       int i, j, min;
       struct temp_tri tr_temp[100];
       double p[101], s[101], area[100];
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
            p[i] = (tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c)*(0.5);
            s[i] = sqrt(p[i]*(p[i]-tr[i].a)*(p[i]-tr[i].b)*(p[i]-tr[i].c));
            area[i] = s[i];    
       }
       //To check whether areas are calculated correctly or not
       /*for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          printf("%d %d %d :- %lf\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c, area[i]);
       }*/
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
          {
              if (area[i] > area[j])
              {
                  tr_temp[i].a = tr[i].a;
                  tr[i].a = tr[j].a;
                  tr[j].a = tr_temp[i].a;
                  
                  tr_temp[i].b = tr[i].b;
                  tr[i].b = tr[j].b;
                  tr[j].b = tr_temp[i].b;

                  tr_temp[i].c = tr[i].c;
                  tr[i].c = tr[j].c;
                  tr[j].c = tr_temp[i].c;
              }
          }
       }
}     

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter no of triangles:- \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    printf("Enter a, b, c:- \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

##### Actual output(n = 10):-

```
26 49 35
67 67 19
41 34 22
48 42 45
33 33 49
61 58 59
3 57 55 
23 43 35
63 46 45
23 12 27
```

##### Expected output:-

```
3 57 55
23 12 27
41 34 22
23 43 35
26 49 35
33 33 49
67 67 19
48 42 45
63 46 45
61 58 59
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) instead of bubblesort.

Comment: You need to swap the areas when you swap the triangles.

Answer (score 4):

You need to swap the area too in your bubble sort implementation:

```c
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (area[i] > area[j]) {
            triangle tr_temp = tr[i];
            double area_temp = area[i];

            tr[i] = tr[j];
            area[i] = area[j];

            tr[j] = tr_temp;
            area[j] = area_temp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another option could be to add `area` to `struct triangle` which would simplify the sorting:

```c
struct triangle {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int area;
};
typedef struct triangle triangle;

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double p = (tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c) * (0.5);
        tr[i].area = sqrt(p * (p - tr[i].a) * (p - tr[i].b) * (p - tr[i].c));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (tr[i].area > tr[j].area) {
                triangle tr_temp = tr[i];
                tr[i] = tr[j];
                tr[j] = tr_temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Adding `area` to `struct triangle` would also make it easy to instead use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) which will be a lot faster than bubblesort when there are a great number of triangles that should be sorted:

```c
int triangle_comp(const void *lhs, const void *rhs) {
    const triangle *l = lhs, *r = rhs;
    if(l->area < r->area) return -1;
    if(l->area > r->area) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double p = (tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c) * (0.5);
        tr[i].area = sqrt(p * (p - tr[i].a) * (p - tr[i].b) * (p - tr[i].c));
    }
    qsort(tr, n, sizeof *tr, triangle_comp);
}
```

Comment: I thought this too.  And another trick would be make triangle wuld be self-evaluating (i.e.  area would be calculated when created) and their container sorted. Yes, total cost would be larger. Judge didn't specify you should sort them after and it could trick the timer

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yes, that may be a possible way to get better scores depending on where the timer is started. OP could experiment to see if that helps.

Comment: It can be said that it's also a useful trick in some applications where we don't want user to wait too long. The most "visible" example would be games loading their assets while playing a cutscene or giving user something to do in meanwhile - reading mission report, managing inventory, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Competition websites will likely fault you if you don't release allocated memory...

You've declared two different `struct`'s, and use both in your code, even though they have exactly the same elements. This is known as a "maintenance nightmare." Keep code as clean as possible.

While Ted was typing his edits, the following was being prepared.

As pointed out in the comment by @user3386109, what's missing is *also* swapping the calculated areas when swapping the triangles' dimensions.

The following is much like @Ted's response, but includes an extra version that uses "compile time initialisation" of the data values. This saves a lot of mucking around with typing or redirection, allowing one to focus on the algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct triangle {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    double area; // "area" is a valid dimension of each triangle
} triangle;

/*  Notice the comment in the next function that tells the reader
    where to look for more info about the algorithm being used...
*/
void calc_areas( triangle* tr, int n ) {
    // Using "Heron's formula" to derive area from 3 sides
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        double hlfPrm = ( tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c ) * 0.5;
        tr[i].area = sqrt( hlfPrm * (hlfPrm-tr[i].a) * (hlfPrm-tr[i].b) * (hlfPrm-tr[i].c) );
    }
}

// use qsort() instead of retyping a sorting algorithm
int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 ) {
    const triangle *pa = p1;
    const triangle *pb = p2;

    if( pa->area > pb->area ) return  1;
    if( pa->area < pb->area ) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main( void ) {
    int n, i;

#ifdef KEYBOARD // version of keyboard entry or redirection from a file.
    printf( "Enter no of triangles:- \n" );
    if( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 )
        return 1; // improve error handling

    triangle *tr = malloc( n * sizeof *tr );
    if( tr == NULL )
        return 1; // improve error handling

    // ALWAYS test return codes, especially for user input!!
    printf( "Enter a, b, c:- \n" );
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        if( scanf( "%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c ) != 3 )
            return 1; // improve error handling
#else // compile time data initialisation
    triangle tr[] = {
        { 26, 49, 35, },
        { 67, 67, 19, },
        { 41, 34, 22, },
        { 48, 42, 45, },
        { 33, 33, 49, },
        { 61, 58, 59, },
        {  3, 57, 55, },
        { 23, 43, 35, },
        { 63, 46, 45, },
        { 23, 12, 27, },
    };
    n = sizeof tr / sizeof tr[0];
#endif

    calc_areas( tr, n );
    qsort( tr, n, sizeof tr[0], cmp );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf( "%8.2f = %2d %2d %2d\n", tr[i].area, tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c );

#ifdef KEYBOARD
    free( tr );
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   62.59 =  3 57 55
  137.29 = 23 12 27
  373.86 = 41 34 22
  401.80 = 23 43 35
  437.49 = 26 49 35
  541.64 = 33 33 49
  630.07 = 67 67 19
  869.02 = 48 42 45
 1034.11 = 63 46 45
 1522.35 = 61 58 59
```